# Empty dictionary are encoded to empty JSON arrays if key is UUID

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to encode/decode JSON with Swift's JSONEncoder/Decoder. My JSON contains a dictionary with UUID as Key. If this dictionary is empty, Swift fails with

```
Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.
```

While analyzing I noticed, that Swift creates different repressions of the empty dictionary depending on the key's type. The following minimum example illustrates the problem quite well:

```
import Foundation

typealias Key = UUID // or String

struct Foo: Codable {
    let data: [Key: String]
}

let foo = Foo(data: [:])
let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(foo)
let foo2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: encodedData)

print(String(decoding: encodedData, as: UTF8.self))
```

When using `UUID` as key's type you get:

```
{"data":[]}
```

and when using `String` as key's type you get:

```
{"data":{}}
```

I'd expect `{"data":{}}` in all cases. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that this was [reported a few years ago](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/issues/3614)